# Kubuntu 15.04 recognizing Wacom Intuos5 as Joystick

Tags: drivers, kubuntu, 15.04, tablet, wacom

[image: Screenshot-WacomasJoystick]I've just upgraded my Kubuntu to 15.04 and I'm having problems with my Wacom Intuos5 settings screen.
Kubuntu is recognizing it as a joystick, the pressure of the pen sometimes go away, I can't disable touch, I can't configure the wacom buttons,,,, in a few words: I can't work.
The last version I used of Kubuntu (14.04, I guess) had a special place for Wacom configuration inside System Settings, in the same place I could configure mouse or joystick.
I tried to install several wacom drivers, but nothing happened.
I need that specific Wacom configuration window.
Please help. Help help.

Thanks
Liz

Answer (score 0):

I'm also having the same problem though with another wacom model (CTL480/S), try opening the Konsole (terminal) and typing:

`xsetwacom list devices`

and see if the system recognizes the "stylus", the "eraser" and the "pad". If yes then I'm assuming that installing wacom drivers is not the case, but finding why there's not a proper gui to configure the tablet.

In the meantime, try giving http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/index_old.php/howto/xsetwacom a try. You can configure your tablet on the terminal with some simple commands.